# The bundle currently has coffee-rails locked at 4.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, coffeescript

I'm learning Ruby on Rails from Michael Hartl's book "Ruby on Rails Tutorial". I have to specify the version number of different gems, so that the app can be deployed via Heroku without conflicts. But when I run `bundle install` I get the above mentioned error message.

Here how the `Gemfile` looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.4'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
end

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %>   in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: Try `bundle update coffee-rails`.

Comment: It might be caused by a difference between the version in `Gemfile.lock` and the version requested in `Gemfile`.

Comment: I tried `bundle update coffee-rails` and got the following error message: `Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby' in any of the gem sources
listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.` Tried to `pip install jquery-rails` while inside my app directory and got the error message:  `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jquery-rails (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for jquery-rails`

Comment: My solution to solve the problem is to change your `gemfile` based on your requirements then use `gem update`. If you are meticulous you can specify the change `gem` packages in the command `gem update gem_package_name`.